# Disable email to admin on new user registration

Tags: users, emails

When a new user registers, an email is sent to the admins. I can't work out how to turn this off. There doesn't seem anywhere where I can alter it. 
In Home » Administration » Configuration » People » Account settings

Who can register accounts? "Visitors" is checked (not "Visitors, but administrator approval is required")

Comment: I check the rules (if installed) to see if there's some other configuration sending out email on user signup.

Answer (score 0):

There are a module for control this emails sendings:
[MailControl](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailcontrol)